# Maximize Complicated Function.

Tags: analysis, inequality, maxima-minima

Let $f : (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the following function

\begin{equation}
f(a) = \frac{(2 p^a - (p+\delta)^a - (p - \delta)^a)^2}{4\ p^a (1-p^a)} 
\end{equation}
where $0<p<1,\ 0< p+ \delta < 1,\ 0 < p- \delta< 1$.

Is it possible to obtain a bound for the maximum value of $f$ as a function of $p, \delta$ or
determine that $f$ is unbounded (going to $+\infty$) ?

I tried differentiating etc. but the expression of the derivative is
too complicated (even for Mathematica) to find its roots.

**EDIT:**

Using Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy's answer we can assume that $p < (p+\delta)^2$ and thus $f$ is bounded. Is it possible to calculate a
bounding value for $f$?

Are there any inequalities to upper bound the numerator 
$(2 p^a - (p+\delta)^a - (p - \delta)^a)^2$ ?

Comment: Do we know anything about the relationship between $p$ and $(p+\delta)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $p^a=t$ and the expression becomes ($4$ dropped)

$$\frac{(2t-t^\alpha-t^\beta)^2}{t(1-t)}$$ where $\alpha:=\dfrac{\log(p+\delta)}{\log p}<1$, $\beta:=\dfrac{\log(p-\delta)}{\log p}>1$ and $t\in(0,1)$.

Close to $t=0$, it simplifies to

$$\left(2t^{1/2}-t^{\alpha-1/2}-t^{\beta-1/2}\right)^2,$$ which is unbounded when $\alpha<1/2$.

Again for small $t$, the expression that is squared can be approximated by dropping the term with the highest exponent, giving

$$2t^{1/2}-t^{\alpha-1/2}$$ or $$2u-u^{2\alpha-1}.$$

The latter has an extremum at

$$u=\left(\alpha-\frac12\right)^{-1/(2\alpha-2)},$$

giving an estimate of the maximum

$$\left(\left(\alpha-\frac12\right)^{-1/(\alpha-1)}-\left(\alpha-\frac12\right)^{-(2\alpha-1)/(2\alpha-2)}\right)^2.$$

Below the function under parenthesis and its approximation (in blue):

[image]

Comment: This needs to be refined and presence of other extrema should be checked.

Comment: The thing is that I need to upper bound this function when $p$ is close to 1. I've managed to do it with carefull Taylor approximations.

Answer (score 1):

The boundedness reduces to studying the limits when $a\to0+$ and $a\to\infty$. Let's look at the latter for starters.

Let $a=2n$ with $n$ positive integer.
Then

\begin{align}
f(2n)&=\frac{(2 p^n - \frac{(p+\delta)^{2n} + (p - \delta)^{2n}}{p^n})^2}{4(1-p^a)}
\end{align}

We can assume $\delta\geq0$.

The denominator tends to $4$.

The $2p^n$ tends to zero.

So, the finiteness of the limit of $f(2n)$ is that of the limit of $$\frac{(p+\delta)^{2n}+(p-\delta)^{2n}}{p^n}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{p-\delta}{p+\delta}\right)^{2n}}{\left(\frac{p}{(p+\delta)^2}\right)^n}$$.

the numerator of this tends to $1$. The denominator ... well it depends if $p/(p+\delta)^2$ is greater than or equal, or smaller than 1.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas to find an upper bound when $f$ is bounded?